# C# Unload managed assembly dll library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dll, .net-assembly

Based on [this Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support), how can i `Unload` a loaded assembly by implementing it in the `AssemblyLoadContext` class? (Considering they are in a global `List<Assembly>`.

I have tried some ways, [this example too](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/main/core/tutorials/Unloading/Host/Program.cs) but nothing seems to really release the dll and let me "delete it" or "overwrite it" with a new one without close the main app.

My goal would be to: load a dll (1.0) => execute the code => unload the dll => replace the *.dll file with a new version (v1.1) => load again the dll => execute the update code.

The actually loading code is this (in .Net 6):

```cs
static IEnumerable<ICommand> Plugs = Enumerable.Empty<ICommand>();
static readonly List<Assembly> PluginAssemblies = new();
static readonly List<string> PluginPath = new();

PluginPath.Add("C:\\...\\Plugin1.dll");
PluginPath.Add("C:\\...\\Plugin2.dll");
PluginPath.Add("C:\\...\\Plugin3.dll");
PluginPath.Add("C:\\...\\Plugin4.dll");

PluginPath.ForEach(P => { PluginAssemblies.Add(LoadPlugin(P)); });

Plugs = Plugs.Concat(PluginAssemblies.SelectMany(A => CreateCommands(A)));
```

And these are the functions from the example:

```cs
static Assembly LoadPlugin(string relativePath)
{
    // Navigate up to the solution root
    string root = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location)))))));

    string pluginLocation = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(root, relativePath.Replace('\\', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));
    Console.WriteLine($"Loading commands from: {pluginLocation}");
    PluginLoadContext loadContext = new PluginLoadContext(pluginLocation);
    return loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(new AssemblyName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pluginLocation)));
}
```

```cs
static IEnumerable<ICommand> CreateCommands(Assembly assembly)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            ICommand result = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ICommand;
            if (result != null)
            {
                count++;
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        string availableTypes = string.Join(",", assembly.GetTypes().Select(t => t.FullName));
        throw new ApplicationException(
            $"Can't find any type which implements ICommand in {assembly} from {assembly.Location}.\n" +
            $"Available types: {availableTypes}");
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

namespace AppWithPlugin
{
    class PluginLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        private AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

        public PluginLoadContext(string pluginPath)
        {
            _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(pluginPath);
        }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(string unmanagedDllName)
        {
            string libraryPath = _resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath(unmanagedDllName);
            if (libraryPath != null)
            {
                return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(libraryPath);
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? The behavior of AppDomains and Assembly Loading changed a lot with .NET Core which is carried-over into .NET 5 and beyond.

Comment: @Dai thanks for the reply. I am using .Net 6. But I don't the example doesn't talk about "AppDomain"

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft, here, [How to use and debug assembly unloadability in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability?source=recommendations)

> calling the AssemblyLoadContext.Unload method just initiates the
> unloading

there are some conditions you need to meet to complete.

1. No threads have methods from the assemblies loaded into the AssemblyLoadContext on their call stacks.
2. None of the types from the assemblies loaded into the AssemblyLoadContext, instances of those types, and the assemblies themselves are referenced by:

- References outside of the AssemblyLoadContext, except for weak references (WeakReference or WeakReference).
- Strong garbage collector (GC) handles (GCHandleType.Normal or GCHandleType.Pinned) from both inside and outside of the AssemblyLoadContext.

In short, **you need to be sure there are no references in memory** to anything in the assemblies you loaded and wait for the GC to do its work.

It seems you're trying to load the assembly, keep the code and unload the assembly from memory keeping the 'command' assigned. That can not be done.

Besides, it doesn't seem you're removing the reference to the assembly from the `PluginAssemblies` list. You need to remove the 'command' from the plugs array too (or use weak references).

I can't see anywhere in your code where you're unloading the assembly. Instead of returning the Assembly object from the LoadPlugin method you can return your PluginLoadContext, so you can call it's Unload method, later when you're sure there are no references left to the assembly or inner classes (clear all assembly or command instances).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The conditions 1, 2 and 3 are ok. The 4° need to be "done" (later i guess). What the app is actually doing is this: Start; Load all plugins; Start in a Task.Parallel all the plugins by executing the common interface; The code in every plugin is just a return of a POST request on a website. And this is in loop. I use also Start/Stop button to Start and Stop the code in the dlls. I'm new on C# so I am not at this level to understand how to unload. Set "null" `PluginAssemblies` and `Plugs` not solve the problem, still can't replace the dll files while the app is running.

Comment: How can I implement a tuple in the `AssemblyLoadContext` so i can call the Unload command from anywhere in the code?

Comment: @Tyler, just on the tuple: avoid using a tuple, instead use a Record

Comment: @GregJF, Is it just an opinion or is there a reason for it?